# Pull mulitple fields when getting dropdown choices from external data source

Tags: infopath, lookup-column, infopath-data-connections

I've tried searching for this as I'm sure others have had the question but can't find a way to word it to find a result.

I have two lists setup - one with a list of people and their data (IDs, First, Middle, Last, etc) and another list for incidents. I wanted to use a lookup at first so I could point to the list of people and pull in multiple fields - Sharepoint does this great.... however it doesn't allow you to sort the list which is why I went the InfoPath route.

I currently have a **dropdown list setup to get choices from an external data source** (the People list) and it's does a fine job... I just can't figure out a way to also pull in additional fields from the people list. For example, I can choose John Smith on the list, but h**ow can I automatically pull his additional fields into the Incident list?**

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint default forms you can use a dropdown for lookup from People's list and extend additional fields in Incidents list(But extended fields will not be shown on forms and they will populate after selection of dropdown).

However according to Microsoft's [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) all types of fields are not supported in lookup columns.

But, If you want to use infopath forms and show additional fields on form, then follow steps given here:

[How to show additional field lookup column](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ec550000-6ac8-4541-9ddc-b8b04b292f6f/how-to-show-additional-field-lookup-column-to-sharepoint-online-add-new-form)